# delayed payment of raise after leaving work

Tags: resignation, raise, payroll

I am leaving a current company and my manager notified me that i got raise starting June. My last day is August 13Th. My manager said they are late with payments but it will be backdated. Am i still eligible to receive to the difference even if i am leaving a company?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have anything in writing confirming that you should have been paid that amount, and starting when?

If so, I would think you ***should*** be entitled to it...

**HOWEVER:** Be very careful about signing any exit paperwork. There's usually a clause in the exit paperwork that states that if you sign it, you're agreeing not to sue for any unpaid wages, raises, etc. Read ***everything*** if you signed/are asked to sign documents on your way out.

If there is such a clause in this document, and you haven't signed it yet... You should consider asking them for that money before signing it.

Companies want to get this paperwork *finished* so that they don't have any lingering liability from previous employees, so if it's a matter of paying you a few thousand bucks to get that handled rather than going to court for it 6-12 months from now, the reasonable ones would generally pay it and move on if pressed about it.

Comment: No, i dont have any document that confirming the fact of payment. However, my manager said it will be backdated for everyone in the company as soon as an owner is back to decide what the raise % for every single person. I have signed off a letter where they explain how i will receive the final pay as some deduction of vacay has to be made and confirming my last day

Comment: If it hasn't even been decided yet, what the amount would be, I don't really believe you'll get it if you've left / given notice by the time they pay it out. Theoretically, they probably *should* do the ethical thing and pay you..... But very likely they'll realize there's no legal consequences to not doing so

Comment: Well, yes, agree, it is more an ethical thing. If they mentioned then it is just their dignity and reputation as an employers to be involved into it. It is a small company and i have good relationships with managers, so it is up to them

Comment: I hope it goes well! From my perspective, I've seen clients literally not pay invoices that they're contractually obligated to pay, for products/services that they are actually satisfied with, because they would rather have the extra cash-flow and profit for their organization and they know they're likely not going to court. This is more of an issue with smaller companies than larger ones, as larger corporations will actually have a bit of a reputation to maintain. Obviously my example is different than your situation, but small companies do not generally let ethics get in the way of success